# Keeping some variables in a list object

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here is sample dataset -

```
entropy_sample <-
structure(list(TICKER = c("NBL", "CIEN", "UAL", "RCL", "NPK", 
"VRSK", "RNET", "APO", "KAR", "SUNS", "QLYS", "SJR", "PRU", "NYT", 
"CAKE", "ETH", "TRN", "TKR", "SM", "GRC", "LAZ", "HHS", "VPG", 
"HNI", "AVX"), sic2 = c("13", "36", "45", "44", "34", "64", "48", 
"62", "73", "67", "73", "48", "63", "27", "58", "25", "37", "35", 
"13", "35", "62", "73", "36", "25", "36"), year = c(2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013), ADOPT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), LNASSETS = c(9.88542540971772, 
7.49707964989703, 10.5135791579587, 9.90712826708477, 5.9751827145337, 
7.82582482782289, 5.47563894425361, 10.0202914868069, 8.54231498019002, 
5.60786244226292, 5.2606310755667, 9.45187378840198, 13.5032365678522, 
7.85265368130371, 7.02475044879817, 6.4253308297364, 8.89746356088984, 
8.4069094655114, 8.45641612048003, 5.87391335957275, 8.01007302728059, 
6.53020101403481, 5.67710990324037, 7.03412798423828, 7.86403373747183
), FOREIGN = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), MERGER = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), ROA = c(0.0684248039914469, 
-0.0444821025421989, 0.0146419645767684, 0.0248390034607275, 
0.148256848096763, 0.215113012792025, 0.107628463629016, 0.110399728516542, 
0.0290997035418942, 0.0462942240452596, 0.0110278656095699, 0.0838045868677348, 
-0.00222060971793474, 0.0368501783443056, 0.139176275715808, 
0.0812817418210389, 0.0807421992506905, 0.0931463409187342, 0.0592138639133803, 
0.124500194017512, 0.0720017056679919, 0.0577898170190916, 0.0184899898666228, 
0.0852265566821332, -0.0435519668562007), DEGREE_D = c(1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Then I use `ebalance` function from `ebal` package for entropy balancing

```
entropy_sample_out <- ebalance(
  Treatment =  entropy_sample$DEGREE_D,
  X = entropy_sample[5:8]
)
```

I use variables 5 through 8 because they are my covariates

I need the `co.xdata` and `w` object from `entropy_sample_out` list, which I can do by running the following code -

```
controls <- as.data.frame(entropy_sample_out$co.xdata) %>% 
  mutate(
    weight = entropy_sample_out$w
  )
```

But I also need to keep four variables - `TICKER`, `sic2`, `ADOPT` and `year` from my `entropy_sample` dataset into  `entropy_sample_out` dataset.

Anybody has idea how I can keep those four variables in `entropy_sample_out` dataset ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the rows with treatment == 0, these should be your control group, and it seems fair to assume the original data order is maintained (althoug a reported index on this in the output would have been nice!)

Just change controls definition to this:

```r
controls <- cbind(
    entropy_sample_out$co.xdata,
    weight = entropy_sample_out$w,
    entropy_sample %>% filter( DEGREE_D == 0 ) %>% select( TICKER, sic2, ADOPT, year )
)
```

Output:

```
> controls
  V1 LNASSETS FOREIGN MERGER        ROA    weight TICKER sic2 ADOPT year
1  1 9.907128       0      0 0.02483900 8.4708041    RCL   44     0 2013
2  1 5.975183       0      0 0.14825685 5.5836765    NPK   34     0 2013
3  1 8.456416       0      0 0.05921386 0.2573489     SM   13     0 2013
4  1 5.873913       1      0 0.12450019 3.8202103    GRC   35     0 2013
5  1 5.677110       1      1 0.01848999 4.3096013    VPG   36     0 2013
```